# MVC / Entity Framework Edit action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entities

I do not understand why this result keeps coming back null. I know ID 100 exist in the database. I am creating online forms that can be stored into a database.  I want to be able to pull them back by ID to update information.

```
public ActionResult reviewPreevent(int? id)
{
    id = 100;
    if (id.HasValue)
    {
        using(formEntities db = new formEntities()) {
            var form = (from a in db.form_preevent
                select new preeventForm
                {
                    id = a.id,
                    meeting = a.meeting,
                    date = (DateTime)a.eventDate,
                    location = a.location,
                    p1Foyer = (bool)a.p1Foyer,
                    p2Foyer = (bool)a.p2Foyer,
                    meetingRoom = (bool)a.meetingroom,
                    skRoom = (bool)a.skroom,
                    kk1 = (bool)a.kk1,
                    kk2 = (bool)a.kk2,
                    nursery = (bool)a.nursery,
                    Sanctuary = (bool)a.sanctuary,
                    kitchen = (bool)a.kitchen,
                    parkingLot = (bool)a.parkinglot,
                    mainLeaders = a.mainleaders,
                    helpers = a.helpers,
                    backup = a.backuphelps,
                    soundboard = (bool)a.soundboard,
                    soundboardtech = a.soundboardtech,
                    projector = (bool)a.projector,
                    projectorOp = a.projectorop,
                    camera = (bool)a.camera,
                    cameraops = a.cameraops,
                    livestream = (bool)a.livestream,
                    ushers = (bool)a.ushers,
                    totalUshers = (int)a.totalushers,
                    greeters = (bool)a.greeters,
                    totalGreeters = (int)a.totalgreeters,
                    security = (bool)a.security,
                    setupTime = (DateTime)a.setuptime,
                    setup = a.setup,
                    breakdown = a.breakdown,
                    foodItems = a.fooditems,
                    groceryShoppers = a.groceryshoppers,
                    foodPrepPersonal = a.foodprep,
                    estExpense = (float)a.estexpense,
                    estIncome = (float)a.estincome,
                    expense = (float)a.expense,
                    income = (float) a.income
                }).Where(t => t.id == id).FirstOrDefault();
            return View();
        }
    }else
    {
        TempData["notice"] = "No form with ID: " + id + " was found.";
        return View();
    }
}
```

Also is there an easier way to match a sql class to a viewmodels class?

Comment: Build a minimal query first: `var form = db.form_preevent.FirstOrDefault(x => x.id == 100);` and see if that works. As for your second question, use [AutoMapper](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html) to copy all those fields.

Comment: Please refine your question or mark one of the below answers as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were so close.  You must return the Form variable when you return the View to the client.

```
public ActionResult reviewPreevent(int? id)
{
    id = 100;
    if (id.HasValue)
    {
        using(formEntities db = new formEntities()) {
            var form = (from a in db.form_preevent
                select new preeventForm
                {
                    id = a.id,
                    meeting = a.meeting,
                    date = (DateTime)a.eventDate,
                    location = a.location,
                    p1Foyer = (bool)a.p1Foyer,
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    income = (float) a.income
                }).Where(t => t.id == id).FirstOrDefault();
            return View(form);  //THIS LINE MODIFIED
        }
    }else
    {
        TempData["notice"] = "No form with ID: " + id + " was found.";
        return View();
    }
}
```